# How can I modify the color of DC.js pieChart drawpaths?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I've got some pie charts with nice external labels, and drawPaths set to true, but I've been unable to get the drawPaths to actually draw.  I'm curious whether there could be something lurking in css that has them set in such a way that they aren't drawing.  As add'l info, I am using dc.js version: '2.0.0-beta.32'

Code for one of the charts looks like this:

```
    zoneChart
     .width(300)
     .height(250)
     .dimension(zoneDim)
     .group(pointsByZone)
     .innerRadius(20)
     .externalLabels(50)
     .drawPaths(true)
     .externalRadiusPadding(50);
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you have a mismatch between your dc.css and the dc.js you are using? The path color is hard-coded at 2px black, nothing dynamic about it. [Here is the relevant part of the css.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/ad5be91e0ffc034e29e4ce32f45eb8872ec404bb/dc.css#L56-L61)

Comment: Ah, gosh, that was it.. thank you Gordon.  So often something simple.  Happen to know whether there is a way to angle the drawpaths such that even the labels for tiny slivers can show up?  Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, that's a great idea. Unfortunately I think you'd have to postprocess to do that now (with the pretransition event), since the code just draws each path at the angle of the slice. I think it would be a matter of assigning different external angles based on the internal angles.